# the fibonnaci sequance javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a function that shows the value of a given number in the Fibonacci sequence. However, it seems the last number is not quite correct on following the Fibonacci algorithm. Any clues on what I am doing wrong here?

```
const fibonacci = function(num) {
    let fsec=[];
    fsec[0]= 0;
    fsec[1]= 1;
    
    for(let i=2; i<=num; i++){
        fsec[i]=fsec[i-2]+fsec[i-1];
        fsec.push(i)
    }

    return fsec[fsec.length-1]
};

fibonacci(6)
```

Comment: remove `fsec.push(i)`

Comment: Rojo is right. You are already adding an element through `fsec[i]=...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fsec.push(i)` is unnecessary and is the problem in this case..

```js
const fibonacci = function(num) {
        let fsec=[];
        fsec[0]= 0;
        fsec[1]= 1;
        
        for(let i = 2; i <= num; i++){
            fsec[i] = fsec[i-2] + fsec[i-1];
        }
        
        return fsec[fsec.length - 1]
};

console.log(fibonacci(6));
```

Comment: worked like a charm, nice code

Comment: No problem.. would appreciate the vote up if possible (:

Answer (score 0):

2 things in your for loop. `i` should be less than `num` and the push should push the number, not the iterator.

Change to this:

```
for(let i=2; i<num; i++){
 fsec[i]=fsec[i-2]+fsec[i-1];
 fsec.push(fsec[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code:

```
const fibonacci = function(num) {
  let fsec=[];
  fsec[0]= 0;
  fsec[1]= 1;
        
  for(let i=2; i<num; i++){
    fsec.push(fsec[i-2]+fsec[i-1])
  }
        
  // console.log(fsec)
  // console.log(fsec[fsec.length-1])
  return fsec[fsec.length-1]                
};

fibonacci(6)
```